# Not able to start flow in corda - java.lang.IllegalStateException: This can only be done after the flow has been started

Tags: corda

New to Corda & I am sure, I am missing something here.

From my API, I am trying to self issue commodities for this I am starting Issue flow using below line:

```
FlowProgressHandle<SignedTransaction> flowHandle = rpcOps
                    .startTrackedFlowDynamic(BlockIssueFlow.class, orderValue);
```

However, my code fails with below exception:

```
[m net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException:
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:238) ~[corda-rpc-3.1-corda.jar:?]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.startTrackedFlowDynamic(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at com.template.ledger.api.GoldBlockAPI.issueGb(GoldBlockAPI.java:88) [cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841) [jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535) [jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) [jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124) [jetty-io-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:243) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597) [jetty-util-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
```

This can only be done after the flow has been started.

Thanks!

Comment: This is odd. Are you able to upload the code anywhere? Also, double-check the logs - is it pointing to a specific error within your flow code?

Comment: Thanks Joel. I have just added my code to https://github.com/amitxpamecha/corda/blob/master/cordapp/src/main/java/com/template/ledger/api/GoldBlockAPI.java
Its issueGb() API from which I am tring to call the flow.

Comment: Probably I have to redesign the way I have written flows. I copied ExampleFlow from sample project, that is running fine. I will refactor and get back to this thread.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you try to access the flow's state machine in the constructor, in order to get access to the node's `ServiceHub`:

```
PartyAndReference partyAndReference = new PartyAndReference(
    getServiceHub().getMyInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0), 
    ref
);
```

The flow state machine is initialised *after* the flow's constructor has been invoked, so the `ServiceHub` cannot be accessed in the constructor.

This PR provides an improved error message for cases like this: https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/3144.

Comment: Took me a while to work out what the issue was, and as per the PR, I'm still getting the old error message in Corda 3.3